# Gazebo 1.8 & DRCSim 2.6 doesn't see new DRC World models

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After updating to the newest Gazebo & DRCSim I am encountering issues downloading the proper models from the models database for the DRC Worlds.

I have deleted the .gazebo/models directory. I have also tried updating the GAZEBO_MASTER_URI to point to the models_latest which allows me to download some, but not all, of the newest models. (e.g. It still can not find mud_box)

I'm not sure if this is something strange since I am behind a proxy server, but when I look at the URL with my browser everything looks okay. Is there somewhere that the contents of the online models database is cached? Is there some other error that I'm encountering? Is this a bug?

Screenshot Here: [http://imgur.com/mZuxTb6](https://imgur.com/mZuxTb6)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2867/gazebo-1.8-&-drcsim-2.6-doesn%27t-see-new-drc-world-models/) by [jhoare](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/83/jhoare/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's a [ticket for this](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/286/mud_box-mud_atlas-models-not-automatically).

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1